# Phrasal Verb request for cover in a cursory manner

Tags: phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

Can someone suggest a phrasal verb which means "not covering something in full detail" or treating the subject in a "cursory manner". Something which implies that the details have been  omitted probably to make the discussion more concise etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skate over.

**skate over**

[Web definition](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=skate+over):

> gloss over: treat hurriedly or avoid dealing with properly

Comment: I would have gone straight for “gloss over” from the definition you gave.

Comment: Collins has: **gloss over** vb (tr, adverb)
1. to hide under a deceptively attractive surface or appearance
2. to deal with (unpleasant facts) rapidly and cursorily, or to omit them altogether from an account of something >> So the 'cover-up' sense is paramount in their thinking. My view is that there is at least a fairly strong connotation of a cover up. 'Skate over' is unmarked for deliberately omitting unpleasant / awkward details.

Answer (score 0):

To give a 'broad-brush treatment to...'

Comment: It's a great answer, but, this came up in the Low Quality Queue.  I'm saying it looks good, but can you flesh it out?  Perhaps explain the origin or meaning of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

cursorily

Adverb;  rapidly and often superficially performed or produced

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cursory

Answer (score -1):

Similar to [Edwin's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155443/24117), to **skim through** or **skim over**.

**[skim](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skim)** *tr. v.*

> to read, study, or examine superficially and rapidly; especially :  to
>   glance through (as a book) for the chief ideas or the plot

There's also **[touch on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/touch-on-upon-sth)**:

> to mention a subject quickly when speaking or writing about another
>   subject